# Is there a way to keep yaxis label(values) such that it follows point on yAxis irrespective of where point moves it must follow it using highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Please refer to below fiddle is it possible to make the yAxis label(Increase/Decrease) binded to 0 such that it follows it irrespective of where it goes.

in my case scale of chart changes after drill down which leads to the label being in the middle of the chart but, position 0 changes drastically I want it to follow where 0 goes.

http://jsfiddle.net/pushpandersingh/jcpbfa64/1/

(async () => {
const { default: Highcharts } =
await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/highcharts.src.js');
await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/highcharts-more.src.js');
await import('https://code.highcharts.com/es-modules/masters/modules/drilldown.src.js');

```
    Highcharts.chart('eqmarketingchartcontainer', {
        chart: {
            height: 550,
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: false,
            events: {
                render: function visibleSeriesCount() {
                    let series = this.series,
                        count = 0;

                    series.forEach(serie => {
                        if (serie.visible) {
                            count++
                            console.log(count + "legend");
                        }
                    })

                    return count;
                },

                drilldown: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    this.setTitle({ text: "<strong> Regional Diffrences in insurance companies' planned risk exposure %</strong><br/><br/>" });
                    if (typeof window.ga === 'function') {
                        window.ga('gtm1.send', 'event', 'insights', 'click', 'click: chart: market: bar');
                        console.log('gtm1.send', 'click: chart: market: bar');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('window.ga is not a function at click: chart: market: bar');
                    }
                },
                drillup: function (e) {
                    this.setTitle({ text: '<strong>Planned changes to risk exposures</strong> (% increase/decrease)' });
                    if (typeof window.ga === 'function') {
                        window.ga('gtm1.send', 'event', 'insights', 'click', 'click: chart: market: back');
                        console.log('gtm1.send', 'click: chart: market: back');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('window.ga is not a function at click: chart: market: back');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            align: 'left',
            text: '<strong>Planned changes to risk exposures</strong> (% increase/decrease)'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: 0,
                style: {
                    color: '#111',
                    fontSize: '.85rem',
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#000000',
                width: 1,
                value: 0,
                zIndex: 5
            }],
            title: {
                text: '<strong>Decrease(%) &emsp; &emsp; Increase(%)</strong>',
                rotation: 270
            }        
        },
        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{y}%',
                    y: 100
                }
            },
            series: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (e) {
                        let series = e.target.chart.series,
                            count = 0,
                            visibleCount = 0,
                            visibleName = '';
                        series.forEach(serie => {
                            if (serie.visible) {
                                visibleCount++;
                                if (visibleCount == 1) {
                                    visibleName = serie.name;
                                }
                            }
                            count++;
                        })

                        if ((this.name == visibleName) && (count <= 1 || visibleCount <= 1)) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        if (typeof window.ga === 'function') {
                            window.ga('gtm1.send', 'event', 'insights', 'click', 'click: chart: market:' + this.name);
                            console.log('gtm1.send', 'click: chart: market:' + this.name);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('window.ga is not a function at market :' + this.name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'left'
        }, credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },



        series: [{
            name: 'Insurance',
            color: '#c3d642',
            data: [{
                name: 'Market risk',
                low: -34,
                high: 39,
                drilldown: 'marketrisk1'
            }, {
                name: 'Credit quality risk',
                low: -36,
                high: 36,
                drilldown: 'creditqualityrisk1'
            }, {
                name: 'Liquidity risk',
                low: -33,
                high: 40,
                drilldown: 'liquidityrisk1'
            }, {
                name: 'Inflation risk mitigation',
                low: -15,
                high: 57,
                drilldown: 'inflationrisk1'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Corporate pension',
            color: '#08bed5',
            data: [{
                name: 'Market risk',
                low: -32,
                high: 40,
                drilldown: 'marketrisk2'
            }, {
                name: 'Credit quality risk',
                low: -34,
                high: 30,
                drilldown: 'creditqualityrisk2'
            }, {
                name: 'Liquidity risk',
                low: -26,
                high: 49,
                drilldown: 'liquidityrisk2'
            }, {
                name: 'Inflation risk mitigation',
                low: -12,
                high: 61,
                drilldown: 'inflationrisk2'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Public pension',
            color: '#ff5048',
            data: [{
                name: 'Market risk',
                low: -41,
                high: 28,
                drilldown: 'marketrisk3'
            }, {
                name: 'Credit quality risk',
                low: -30,
                high: 35,
                drilldown: 'creditqualityrisk3'
            }, {
                name: 'Liquidity risk',
                low: -32,
                high: 36,
                drilldown: 'liquidityrisk3'
            }, {
                name: 'Inflation risk mitigation',
                low: -10,
                high: 63,
                drilldown: 'inflationrisk3'
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            breadcrumbs: {
                floating: true,
                position: {
                    y: -25
                },
                showFullPath: true
            },
            series: [{
                id: 'marketrisk1',
                name: 'Insurance',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -24,
                    high: 46
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -40,
                    high: 39
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -31,
                    high: 28
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'creditqualityrisk1',
                name: 'Insurance',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -22,
                    high: 41
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -38,
                    high: 40
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -44,
                    high: 21
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'liquidityrisk1',
                name: 'Insurance',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -24,
                    high: 51
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -35,
                    high: 36
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -36,
                    high: 38
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'inflationrisk1',
                name: 'Insurance',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -12,
                    high: 49
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -16,
                    high: 62
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -15,
                    high: 54
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'marketrisk2',
                name: 'Corporate pension',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -43,
                    high: 32
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -25,
                    high: 45
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -33,
                    high: 42
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'creditqualityrisk2',
                name: 'Corporate pension',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -39,
                    high: 29
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -34,
                    high: 33
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -26,
                    high: 23
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'liquidityrisk2',
                name: 'Corporate pension',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -23,
                    high: 55
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -30,
                    high: 42
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -19,
                    high: 58
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'inflationrisk2',
                name: 'Corporate pension',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -10,
                    high: 71
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -11,
                    high: 54
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -19,
                    high: 65
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'marketrisk3',
                name: 'Public pension',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -33,
                    high: 26
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -43,
                    high: 30
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -48,
                    high: 29
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'creditqualityrisk3',
                name: 'Public pension',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -23,
                    high: 36
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -33,
                    high: 35
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -39,
                    high: 32
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'liquidityrisk3',
                name: 'Public pension',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -30,
                    high: 39
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -31,
                    high: 35
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: -39,
                    high: 39
                }]
            }, {
                id: 'inflationrisk3',
                name: 'Public pension',
                showInLegend: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'NORAM',
                    low: -20,
                    high: 58
                }, {
                    name: 'EMEA',
                    low: -18,
                    high: 59
                }, {
                    name: 'APAC',
                    low: 0,
                    high: 84
                }]
            }]
        }



    });
    $('#eqmarketingchartcontainer').removeAttr('style');
})();
```

Comment: Do you want a constant value on the yAxis? For this, you can set the [yAxis.max](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max) value on 
 the yAxis, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0or2hL4z/).

Comment: Hi thanks for replying @SebastianHajdus No that's not what I meant if you see along the yAxis there's label named VALUES on left of y-axis which is also rotated. I want to bind it to position of 3 on yAxis such that when chart expands/shrinks after drilldown/drillup it's aligned to position of 3 as of now it's by default aligned in middle which is middle of the chart I'm trying to bind it to a Yaxis point's position such that it's always adjacent to that particular point. Hope it would help understand my case better I'll try to attach image in question to make it bit clearer.

Comment: Can you show a picture/gif to better understand your case?